# Netbeans 7.2 won't open on OS X

Tags: java, osx-lion, netbeans-7

I installed Netbeans on OSX Mountain Lion running JDK 7. Everything was working fine. Then my machine for no reason crashed. After this I could no longer open Netbeans anymore.

If I try to start Netbeans from the commandline:

```
/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.2.app/Contents/MacOS/netbeans
```

Then it works fine. From there I can select Netbeans > About and confirm that my userdir and cachedir is:

```
User directory: /Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/NetBeans/7.2
Cache directory: /Users/<user>/Library/Caches/NetBeans/7.2
```

So, I deleted these directories and tried again, but alas, I can only start netbeans via the commandline.

Ideas appreciated...

Comment: im sure Netbeans outputs error logs, i'd check there first.

Comment: Deleting NetBeans's cache has helped me with NetBeans borks in the past.  You can find the cache in the _var_ folder of your _.netbeans_ directory.  My _.netbeans_ folder is in my home directory.

Comment: Strangely, if I drag the netbeans executable shortcut (/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans\ 7.2.app/Contents/MacOS/netbeans) into the dock, I can run the "exec" icon. It opens a terminal window, runs the command, and opens Netbeans just fine!

Answer (score 3):

Sounds to me like this is not a NetBeans problem at all, rather a problem with the bundle, such that OS X is not launching the app as it should.

To verify, I'd try opening NetBeans *through Finder from the command line*:

`open -a "NetBeans 7.2.app"`

This command will ask the system launcher to open the application as if you had clicked on the icon. In your case, it probably won't open. If this is true, then you know it's not something in your terminal *environment* that's allowing NetBeans to launch.

The next step that I would take would be to look at the package contents: examine `/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.2.app/Contents/Info.plist` for anything that seems amiss - this file is the information store that OS X looks for to see how to launch the package, what its icon is, etc... - in particular, I think you should look at the `CFBundleExecutable` value to see what command is used to launch the app. If it's not `netbeans`, you've found a big hint on what might be amiss: bundles are set up so that launchers should run `bundle_dir.app/Contents/{platform}/{CFBundleExecutable_value}`. Looking at CFBundleExecutable should show you if there's some other script used to launch the app than just running `netbeans`.

From this point, you'll have to do more digging, but hopefully this is enough information for you to get started tracking down how apps are launched from the OS X launcher. For more info and a better reference, check out [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html), which is Apple's documentation for keys in `Info.plist`.

Finally, you should note that the launch information for all apps are heavily cached; I've heard that if you make a change to Info.plist, you have to rename the app bundle and name it back to have the changes picked up by the launcher.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi @Matt, thanks for your answer. Strangely, open -a "NetBeans 7.2.app" did actually work, but the icon is still toast. The value in Info.plist for CFBundleExecutable is indeed netbeans, but double-clicking the icon still doesn't work... I awarded you the bounty as it has one hour left and your answer is the closest.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea: use Eclipse >=)

..but seriously, something got corrupted in Netbeans' metadata/cache data files. You cleared a couple of them but there may be others elsewhere.

Try comparing the launch command in your shortcut to what you're typing in the console. Are they the same?

Comment: I'm not an Apple person, but on KDE or even Windoze you can right click the shortcut and go to properties (or whatever it's called) and see the command. Example: http://i47.tinypic.com/5ygo79.png

Answer (score 1):

To find the root cause, I would check the NetBeans logs, as detailed [here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqLogMessagesFile)

> /Users/yourname/Library/Application Support/NetBeans/7.2/var/log/messages.log

---

And if that doesn't help, I'd archive your project(s) and put a clean install of NetBeans on your machine, and then import the archived project(s) back into NetBeans.

Comment: Already checked. Nothing being logged via "icon" version. Commandline version logging as expected.

Comment: @MarkvanWyk, Launch details aren't even being logged? And by "icon" version, do you mean launching NetBeans via a shortcut? If so, I'd check to see if it calls the same executable as the commandline

Comment: Yes, launch details not being logged. Yes, I mean the application archive "/Applications/Netbeans\ 7.2.app" can't be clicked.